# How to disable Spring Security's login screen?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, authentication

Spring Security causes / or any path to redirect to `/login`, and `/login` to generate and serve a login form. I tried many options like adding these lines to my properties file

```
security.ignored=/**
spring.security.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false
security.basic.enabled=false
```

Nothing worked.

[image]

This has been deprecated maybe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems `security.ignored=/**` has been moved out from Spring Boot 2.x as if `Spring Security` is on the `classpath`, Spring Boot will add `@EnableWebSecurity` so adding entries to the `application.properties` ain't gonna work.

Here is how you can disable by configuring security config...

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }
}
```

[Security changes in Spring Boot 2.0 M4](https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/15/security-changes-in-spring-boot-2-0-m4)

Comment: In some cases, it is necessary to disable CSRF protection too: `.csrf().disable()`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Spring Security from the classpath:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This will remove a barrier that forces the user to sign in before seeing a page.

Comment: you can't be serious!

Comment: @louloumilo: Why? If you don't use Spring Security at all, you don't need it on class path.

Comment: This works in some cases, but in my case the login was still here because of the oath2 client which depends on security

Comment: ^ Same. I wanted only the OAuth2RestTemplate in spring-security-oauth2 which depends on security-core. I don't want to enable the web security and login screen. I am stuck.